# Assigning values to a variable from inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Have an issue with scope in javascript and cant work out how to pass a value out

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  availableTags = new Array();
  $.getJSON('index.php?getTagList', function(data) {
      availableTags = data;
      alert(data);
  });
  alert(availableTags);
});
```

I know that the data is right and the alert confirms it but how do i assign it to the availableTags variable? seriousli strigling with scope in javascript...

Comment: Not a scope issue; the `getJSON` callback function runs chronologically last.

Comment: Another duplicate: [jQuery async ajax query and returning value problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931100/jquery-async-ajax-query-and-returning-value-problem-scope-closure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `$.getJSON(url, callback)` is asynchronous. The callback hasn't executed (and set the `availableTags` variable) before you try to alert the `availableTags` variable.

Comment: What Rob said. Basically, you need to put the rest of your code into the `$.getJSON` function, or call another function with the returned data.

Comment: Thanks Rob, keep forgetting :)